# Why I can't render my `<div>` by using hyperscript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
<div id="search" class="mainContent debug"></div>
</body>
<script src="http://www.csc.kth.se/~cristi/hyperscript/0.1.js"></script>
```

```
h("div",id="search",      
      h("div",      
            h("input"),  

            h("select",h("option",123),h("option",456) ), 

            h("button", "Search!") 
       ),   
       h("div")    
).render(this.root);
```

When I open it in browser it returned an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.el.render`
How to slove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the example the target element is regocnized by `"div#search"` ...

Comment: @Teemu， Sorry it doesn't work, it returned an error`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The qualified name provided ('div#search') contains the invalid character '#'.`